# Horizontally align thumbnails in center

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails, alignment

Following is the code I'm using in my html with twitter-bootstrap. I am trying to center align the output but the image is left-aligned no matter what I do.

```
<ul class="thumbnails"> 
   <li class="span5">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="img.jpg" /></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Any simple solution?

Comment: `text-align: center` on the `li`

Comment: already tried that, no effect! ;(

Comment: Unless the `li`s are `display: inline` or the `img`s are `display: block` that should work. Could you show the site/code?

Comment: @powerbuoy yes the image is display: block. the site is currently offline so cannot show it. but here is the screenshot of the front-end code from the firebug.. http://www.freeimagehosting.net/um4qj

Comment: Block elements can be centered by setting their left and right margins to `auto`. Or you could just change them to `inline`.

Comment: @powerbuoy the left and right margins are already 'auto', changing the  left and right marging to 'inline' just disappears them in firebug and  isn't producing any effect. may be i've messed it up by linking to bootstrap.css and bootstrap-1.1.1.css both at once.

Comment: No you should change the `display` property of the `img` elements to `inline` so that `text-align: center` affects them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Twitter bootstrap thumbnails are floated to the left by default, you have to overwrite that behavior on your own stylesheet in order to make them center align its container with the `text-align:center` and `display:inline-block` properties. Try this:

**CSS**

```
.thumbnails {
    text-align:center;
}

.thumbnails > li {
    display: inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* ie7 fix */
    float: none; /* this is the part that makes it work */
}
```

This way the thumbail images will center inside the `.thumbnails` container. Replace the `.thumbnail` class with the container you want to center your images in.

Comment: Woah woah woah, this is the first in my life I see that > syntax in CSS. What does it mean?

Comment: @Leonnears It is called the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) and is used to only select all children of an element, as opposed to all matching elements within. In this case, it is used to select the first level (children) list items of the `.thumbnails` container.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `text-align: center;` and give your `img` `display: inline-block;` it should become center aligned.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/HWMZg/

Answer (score 1):

This is simple just add:

```
<div class="thumbnail" style="margin:0px auto;">whatever image tag here ...</div>
```

Hope this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

I found this works easiest for Bootstrap:

```
.thumbnails > li {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

I simply changed "float" from "left" to "right"

Answer (score 0):

Create a new row for the image.  Use the appropriate offset depending on the size of your image e.g.:

```
<div class="span8 offset2" >
```